# Counting and grouping number of occurrencies in R

Tags: r, group-by, counting

I have a dataset which has the variables "**customerID**" and "**Country**". Of course there are several instances with the same **customerID**, because it's a dataset containing yearly data of a retail store. I would like to *count the number of customers by country*, but the problem is that I don't know how to "**increase**" the counter only one time for each **customerID**. I think that I have to use both the `table()` and `unique()` functions, but I can't figure out how.

The dataset looks like this

```
    InvoiceNo   StockCode    CustomerID        Country
1   536365      70897a       17850             United Kingdom     
2   536365      71053        17850             United Kingdom
3   536365      84406B       17850             United Kingdom
4   536366      22752        18652             United Kingdom
5   536367      66543        18652             United Kingdom
6   536368      71053        17556             USA
```

I would like to have a table(or dataframe) in return like this

```
United Kingdom     USA
             2       1
```

Comment: Probably, u can use `group by` function on `customer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R method using `table` and subsetting:

```
with(unique(df[c("CustomerID", "Country")]), table(Country))
Country
United_Kingdom            USA 
             2              1
```

To get a data.frame, wrap this is `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(with(unique(df[c("CustomerID", "Country")]), table(Country)))
         Country Freq
1 United_Kingdom    2
2            USA    1
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="InvoiceNo   StockCode    CustomerID  Country
536365      70897a       17850             United_Kingdom
536365      71053        17850             United_Kingdom
536365      84406B       17850             United_Kingdom
536366      22752        18652             United_Kingdom
536367      66543        18652             United_Kingdom
536368      71053        17556             USA")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think the `table` function is the way to go. If you have issue with duplicated rows, you might want to clean those up first. For example, you can use numerical indices to get around that problem.

Once you get `table` working, you can make a summary table. Here is a hypothetical example:

```
summary_table <- data.frame(
    customerID_count=table(your_data$_customerID), 
    country_count = table(your_data$country)
)
```

(ps: good job asking your first question and get started with stackoverflow. You should include a working example)

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can use `group_by` and `summarise` functions in `dplyr` package

I have created a sample dataframe only with customerID (V1) and country(V2)

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c("17850","17850","17850","18652","18652","17556"),V2=c("UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","USA"))
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(V2) %>% summarise(count=length(unique(V1)))

      V2 count
1     UK     2
2    USA     1
```